# Django admin formset : How to use jQuery adding a new row of formset?

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, django-admin

In the django admin adding page, when using `TabularInline` it has a anchor `Add another Poll` which's html looks like

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Add another Poll</a>
```

Now I want to add a new row, just like using mouse click on the anchor, when file input change event is triggered :

```
$('input:file').change(function(e){
    //... do something ...
    var rows = "#poll_set-group .tabular.inline-related tbody tr";
    var addbtn = $(rows).parent().find("tr:last a")
    addbtn.click(); // try to add a new row but doesn't work
});
```

Element selection is correct but click() doesn't work. I also tried `addbtn.trigger('click')` though it almost doing the same thing and still doesn't work.

When I trace into the Django's inline.js can see the binded function

inline.js

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.formset = function(opts) {
        ///...
        if ($(this).length && showAddButton) {
            var addButton;
            if ($(this).attr("tagName") == "TR") {
                //...
                addButton = $(this).parent().find("tr:last a");
            } else {
                //...
                addButton = $(this).filter(":last").next().find("a");
            }
            addButton.click(function() {
            //...
            });
        } 
    }
})(django.jQuery);
```

Could anyone tell me why `.click()` doesn't work?
Or any other suggestion to do the same thing?

Comment: i didn't find code for `addbtn.click()`(you are calling this but no implementation ) have you miss something to post?

Comment: I thought the click() implementation is already binded to `addButton.click(...` when calling `$(rows).formset(...)` after document ready. All I have to do is to trigger the click event. Is my imagination wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having tried several hours, i found how to do that and have learned some key points during process.

1.using `.data` to store local object in the plugin. (not sure will or not cause memory leak or any other problems)

inline.js

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.formset = function(opts) {
        ///...
        if ($(this).length && showAddButton) {
            var addButton;
            if ($(this).attr("tagName") == "TR") {
                //...
                addButton = $(this).parent().find("tr:last a");
            } else {
                //...
                addButton = $(this).filter(":last").next().find("a");
            }

            // store local object 'addButton' into data()
            var $this = $(this), data = $this.data('addButton')
            if( !data ){
                $this.data('addButton', {
                    target : addButton,
                });
            }

            addButton.click(function() {
            //...
            });
        } 
    }
})(django.jQuery);
```

2.jQuery object instance exists in its own namespace ( django.jQuery for this example )

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    (function($) {
        var rows1 = "#poll_set-group .tabular.inline-related tbody tr";
        $(rows1).formest({...});
    })(django.jQuery);

    var rows2 = "#poll_set-group .tabular.inline-related tbody tr";
    $(rows2).data('addButton')
    // Error, rows2's data is empty
    // cause of although rows1 & rows2 have same selector, but they are different objects in the different namespaces

    // use django.jQuery(rows2) to get the same object instance of rows1
    // this can trigger the same event handler being bound in the plugin inline.js
    django.jQuery(rows2).data('addButton').target.click(); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`addbtn` and `addButton` are different objects, and therefore have different click event handlers. You would have to extend `addButton` to add additional event handlers. Also, events that are bound on DOM ready, like:

```
$('input:file).change();
```

only apply to elements that are present when the DOM is loaded, and won't be applied to future elements of that selector. To do that, you need to use [.live()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live)

Comment: i have some questions...
1. if `addbtn` and `addButton` are different objs, why clicking on the "a" can trigger `addButton.click`?
2. can i have some ways to get the `addButton` object?
3. how to extend the local object `addButton` being in the jQuery plugin?

Comment: On closer inspection of the selectors, it appears there's some overlap, which would explain why you're seeing the event in both places. Unfortunately, I'm not as versed in JavaScript as I would like to be, so I'm not sure how best to extend `addButton`